# User scenario testing for Java Applications on PC

Tags: java, test-framework, gui-test-framework

I'm looking for a good Testing-Framework for Java GUI Applications. For Android I know Robotium and it would be really cool if there is something similar for Java PC Applications.

Example Testcase:
 1. Right click on TreeView
 2. Click on Menuitem "Expand all"
 3. Check if Tree has been expanded and there is a new item visible with maybe "RAM" as text.

I searched for Java Test frameworks but didn't found anything like Robotium.

What are you using to test your Java GUIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have severel options

- [FEST](http://fest.easytesting.org/) - compatible with TestNG and JUnit, framework is written to be use specially for Swing testing so it's very fast, in can take screenshots after failures, even sometimes determine the cause of this failure and other features. I would defintely give this one a tyr
- [Marathon](http://marathontesting.com/) - looks very cool too, also has handful of features but unfortunately has a paid license
- [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) - image-based testing framework, allows you to write test scripts in Java
- [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) - you can write your tests in plain English, looks very interesting, so I would definitely give this one a shot
- and others...

As you can see, there are many frameworks, so the best is probably to go through their examples and basic tutorials and just grab what fits you the most.

Answer (score 0):

- What about [fest](http://code.google.com/p/fest/)?
- What about [ranorex](http://www.ranorex.com/)?
- What about [swinger](https://github.com/demetriusnunes/swinger)?
- What about [Marathon](http://marathontesting.com/)?